# Instamojo Payment Integration - Webhook Issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, instamojo

The response from the instamojo api is successfully extracted but the issue is that, the webhook service is not working. In this I've provided a webhook url in request and i want to exclude the CSRF verification, for that I've included Except array with `'instamojo/*'` in middleware but still no use.

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'instamojo/*',
    ];
}
```

The current Route

```
Route::post('webhook','HomeController@webhook');
```

Comment: So your webhook fails because it gets a CSRF error?

Comment: yes correct when i add '*' in except array of CSRF middleware file then it works fine. But i only want to exclude the Instamojo URL.

Comment: Can you add your routing code related to *Instamojo* to the question?

Comment: ya.i will provide

Comment: So you should add to the middleware `'webhook/*'` instead of instamojo.

Comment: k I'wil try and update you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172066/discussion-between-hari17-and-thefallen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be solved by adding the posting route name in middleware's Except section.
Here I added `webhook/*` in my middleware.

**Route**

```
Route::post('webhook','HomeController@webhook');
```

**Middleware**

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'webhook/*',
    ];
}
```

It work's fine.Thank you.